# Why does my sprite does not move beyond the first waypoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: The waypoints are present on the way through the maze exits image]

[image: The Unity Screenshot Image with hierarchy]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieControl : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
Transform[] waypoints;

[SerializeField]
float moveSpeed = 2f;

int wayPointIndex =0;

void Start()
{
    transform.position = waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position;
}

void Update() {
    Move ();
}

void Move()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, waypoints [wayPointIndex].transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position == waypoints [wayPointIndex].transform.position) {
        wayPointIndex += 1;
    }

    if (wayPointIndex == waypoints.Length)
        wayPointIndex = 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because your transform.position never exactly equals your waypoint position because of the accuracy of floats. You should be using a tolerance when using equalities with floats.

```
if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position) < .05f) // or some other small distance
{
    wayPointIndex += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Solved the problem.

Comment: I'd recommend using the square magnitude instead of the distance. There's really no reason to know the *exact* distance so using Square mag can save a little bit of computation time.

Answer (score 1):

Vector2 is based on floats, and floats frequently don't quite exactly equate due to minor rounding issues. So this line of code probably never returns true:

```
if (transform.position == ...
```

See notes at:
https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector2.Equals.html

Try testing the distance between them instead (or better, the square of the distance is faster to calculate).

```
Vector2 difference = transform.position - waypoints [wayPointIndex].transform.position;

if ( difference.SqrMagnitude() < 0.001 ) {
    wayPointIndex += 1;
}
```

If it doesn't work at first, experiment with the threshold to find a value that suits your needs.

If you're doing this a lot, create a helper function. E.g, a similar example for Vector3 at:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/395513/vector3-comparison-efficiency-and-float-precision.html

Comment: Thanks so much. Solved the problem.